# Spring actuator in non mvc application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I added `spring-boot-starter-actuator` to maven in non mvc application, I added `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*`, when I try to view it on the browser, I get infinity loading, how can I saw metrics?

Comment: Actuator will only work in a web based architecture else there is nothing to expose (as there is no server being started). No server no http endpoints. You can enable JMX and have metrics exposed over JMX or have them exported to New Relic or whatever you use to collect metrics.

Comment: I run my application on tomcat, so I think that it is non mvc application but it is server

Comment: Regardless if there is no MVC infrastructure how should endpoints be exposed... You haven't configured your app for it so there is nothing to use to expose the endpoints.

Comment: got it, but why i get infinity loading?